# excel rows function: increase multiple numbers in different ways within same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rows, worksheet-function

I am using an Excel spreadsheet in order to  auto increase numbers within text.  I have been using the rows function to auto increase numbers by 1: `="text"&ROWS(A$1:A1)&"text"

This produces the following output:

(CELL A:1) text1
(CELL A:2) text2
(CELL A:3) text3..etc

I now need add to another number which repeats itself 7 times and then increases by 1. I also need another number which runs from 1 to 6 and then repeats this cycle.  This would produce the following output:

(CELL A:1) text1 text1 text1

(CELL A:2) text2 text1 text2

(CELL A:3) text3 text1 text3

(CELL A:4) text4 text1 text4

(CELL A:5) text5 text1 text5

(CELL A:6) text6 text1 text6

(CELL A:7) text7 text1 text7

(CELL A:8) text8 text2 text1

(CELL A:9) text9 text2 text2

(CELL A:10) text10 text2 text3

(CELL A:11) text11 text2 text4

(CELL A:12) text12 text2 text5

(CELL A:13) text13 text2 text6

(CELL A:14) text14 text2 text7 ...etc

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Divide by 7 or 6, rounding up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify the numbering pattern?

section 1(column 1) is just the row it's in correct?
section 2(column 2) increments every 7 rows
section 3(column 3) increments every row but indexes with column 2?

```
 ="text " & ROW() & " text " & ROUNDUP(ROW() / 7,0) & " text " & IF(MOD(ROW(), 7) = 0, 7, MOD(ROW(), 7))
```

That produces what you provided.. I think...

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly, you've saved me a lot of time, much appreciated.